# How to include an external CRD inside custom CRD, but the external CRD is not available in Go?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I am building an operator using Kubebuilder that creates a CRD that encapsulates an external CRD (ex: Airflow's DAG CRD https://github.com/cdmikechen/airflow-dag-operator/blob/main/example/02-crd.yaml).

My operator will use its CRD to delegate the creation of the DAG CRD to the Airflow operator and alongside other orchestration tasks.

What is the best way to import the Airflow CRD into my kubebuilder project? Do I have to manually copy it because the Airflow CRD was only implemented in Java?